# Find $\int \frac{1}{x^7-x}dx$.

Tags: calculus

> Find $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{x^7-x}dx$.

I've seen methods break this up into partial fractions but what is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Partial fractions is probably the easiest and straightforward because both the integrals lend themselves as logs.  The integrand is $\frac{\frac166x^5}{x^6 -1} - \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $x^5 $. Let $y = x^6 $.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate on the previous answer, let $u=1-x^{-6}$. Then $$\frac{dx}{x^7-x} = \frac{du}{6u}$$

Comment: are you supposed to see that without having done partial fractions? Otherwise how is it helpful to OP to learn that, if you know the answer, you can make it look easy?

Comment: As I said, I was elaborating on the other answer, which suggested "taking out" $x^{7}$. $$\frac{1}{x^7-x} = \frac{1}{x^7}\frac{1}{1-x^{-6}}.$$Partial fractions is definitely the "book" answer, however. @MichaelChirico

Comment: I don't mean to denigrate. Just that if you could explain how one might have noticed this approach, it would be much more helpful to OP

Answer (score 4):

Take $x^7$ outside of the denominator. The other term's derivative is $1/{x^7}$. Its pretty evident from there.